# Why is Physics Stack Exchange now plain text?

Tags: support

I realised that suddenly, Physics.SE and meta have both gone plain text! Even LaTeX support has disappeared! What has happened? Is this a bug or was this done for a reason?

**Edit:** It is fine now. It had been like that for around half an hour, though.

Comment: You may have a bad version of some java script in your cache. Trying clearing caches and/or forcibly reloading the whole page.

Comment: If you have problems with the display of Physics SE, you can alternativel go [here](http://motls.blogspot.de/2013/07/cumrun-vafa-strings-and-magic-of-extra.html) to read some interesting physics. In addition you can ping me there, if you want to talk to me. There is nothing else that can be done to help you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised.  

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDN may have failed for your location. Or your net connection is unstable. Or your JS/CSS cache got corrupted.

Nothing that can be fixed on our side, usually waiting it out for a while works.